# Human-readable text file format for game parameters

Tags: file-format, configuration

Basically what I want to do is put a lot of different parameters in a text file I edit by-hand, to avoid recompiling. I'm using Ogre3D, so I'm using configfile, but it gets messed up, and I'm looking for something with more features.

I've tried YAML-CPP, but it seems to be a pain to use, I had a very hard time figuring out how to make a difference between a pair and a mapping.

XML is a no-no, it's not human readable.

My program only reads the file, and I always edit it by hand.

Any C-like format ?

Comment: You'd be better off asking about your yaml-cpp-related confusion on Stack Overflow. Then you can use YAML.

Comment: XML is perfectly readable by humans. It may be more verbose than some other alternatives, but that it is entirely different criticism.

Comment: Hm, negative ratings.. figures: "XML - not human readable".. odd statement :|. I also use Ogre and I'd like to understand why the configuration input file "gets messed up". Ogre has a powerful architectural design behind it and I don't think it lacks that much from this point of view. But there's always room for improvement.

Comment: what about C like syntax ?

Comment: Go back and recheck YAML - it's pretty common and there are many libraries for accessing it available.  Also, C is a language so I'm not sure what a "C-like format" is.

Comment: +1 to Tim's comment - YAML is definitely the way to go if you want human-readable. You might also investigate JSON or LUA.

Comment: Also check INI format.  Kind of like YAML but really simplistic.

Comment: For C-like format: like materials http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Materials

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple format for many programs, where each line
consists of a key,value pair.  It's easy for both humans
and programs to parse.

```
#
# this is a comment line
#
keyname,this is the value of the key "keyname"
key2,this is a multi line key called "key2"
,this is the continuation of the previous line
```